# Large files download/upload Blob Storage Azure

Tags: c#, azure-blob-storage, .net-6.0, angular14

I'm working with some interactions with Azure blob storage. Download, Upload and get files. But I'm having a lot of problems when the file is large (100mib +).
The first problem is the slowness, both in downloading and uploading. The front application, at a certain point, needs to list some content and for each iteration, the backend application needs to go to storage to get the binary from the file (it's not my fault haha).

I read some articles that helped me a little, but I still need some tips. I would be very grateful if you could help me:

How to improve this performance? I read something about not using MemoryStream and parallelism requests (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blobs-tune-upload-download)

To not make it too long, I'll put some parts of the code:

```
        public async Task<bool> Upload(IFormFile CaminhoRelativo, string CaminhoRelativo, string contentType, bool NaoComprimir = false)
        {
            string path = BlobHelper.GerarArquivoPath(arquivo.FileName, CaminhoRelativo);
            await _cloudBlobContainer.CreateIfNotExistsAsync();
            CloudBlockBlob blockBlobReference = _cloudBlobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(path);
            try
            {
                MemoryStream memoryStream = BlobHelper.GerarArquivoStream(arquivo);
                if (NaoComprimir)
                {
                    await blockBlobReference.UploadFromStreamAsync(memoryStream);
                    CloudBlockBlob blockBlobReference2 = _cloudBlobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(CaminhoRelativo + "/" + arquivo.FileName);
                    blockBlobReference2.Properties.ContentType = contentType;
                    await blockBlobReference2.SetPropertiesAsync();
                }
                else
                {
                    using MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream(CompressaoHelper.ComprimirArquivoGZIP(memoryStream));
                    await blockBlobReference.UploadFromStreamAsync(memStream);
                }
            }
            catch (StorageException ex)
            {
                throw new Exception("Erro ao tentar fazer o upload do arquivo: " + path + ". Detalhes: " + ex.Message);
            }

            return true;
        }
```

What is the best approach to conversions and traffic across the information network? Byte array, Base 64?

Thank you very much!

Comment: The question code caches the contents in memory (MemoryStream is a wrapper over a byte array). There's a lot of missing code here eg GerarArquivoPath, ComprimirArquivoGZIP, but if any of these load 100MB in memory, the application will be slow no matter what. You could use [IFormFile.OpenReadStream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.iformfile.openreadstream?view=aspnetcore-7.0#microsoft-aspnetcore-http-iformfile-openreadstream) to read directly from the uploaded file and push to Azure with `blockBlobReference.UploadFromStreamAsync`, assuming no interruption

Comment: What is the code trying to do? Why isn't it just saving the file locally then uploading it? And what does `the back application needs to go to storage to get the binary` mean? A 100MB is a large file, no matter how you deal with it. This has nothing to do with arrays vs BASE64, although converting bytes to text before uploading won't help at all. What would help is to extract what information you want and store it as Blob metadata, or in a separate file containing that file's metadata. This way you'd only have to read a few bytes instead of 100MB

Comment: To move large files in general its better to upload them in blocks, even concurrently, and then reconstruct the file from those blocks. If a block upload fails, you can retry it without having to restart the entire file. Azure Blob Storage offers [block blobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/understanding-block-blobs--append-blobs--and-page-blobs#about-block-blobs) for exactly this scenario.

Comment: The Azure [Data Movement library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-data-movement-library?toc=%2Fazure%2Fstorage%2Fblobs%2Ftoc.json&bc=%2Fazure%2Fstorage%2Fblobs%2Fbreadcrumb%2Ftoc.json) simplifies the transfer of large files by splitting the file in blocks and uploading them in parallel

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I corrected some parts of the text. I didn't want to paste too much code here to avoid confusion. The big issue is that this code was written in 2022 and I know that there are several ways nowadays to handle large files. Is using the memorystream really the big problem? Note: sorry for my English.

Comment: Yes, it's a humongous problem because you may be storing 200MB in memory for every 100MB file. None of these concepts are new. Download managers used blocked downloads and uploads in the 1990s and 2000s too. Block storage was one of the very first Azure Blob storage options, built for *exactly* this scenario.

Comment: Other alternatives depend on where your code is running. Is it a local web site? Or does it run on Azure itself? If the site runs on Azure stream copying may *not* be a bad option. Another option is to create a one-use URL to the final blob and have the *client* upload to it directly. [This blog posts](https://markheath.net/post/upload-azure-blob-storage-sas) shows how to do this with C#

Answer (score 0):

> Large files download/upload Blob Storage Azure

I agree with Panagiotis Kanavos 's comment if you need to upload/download a large file you can use the **[Azure data movement library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-data-movement-library)**.

Here is my sample code to upload a large file size of 250 MB file transfer from local to Azure blob storage.

**Code:**

```
class program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string storageConnectionString = "<Storage connection string>";
        CloudStorageAccount account = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(storageConnectionString);
        CloudBlobClient blobClient = account.CreateCloudBlobClient();
        CloudBlobContainer blobContainer = blobClient.GetContainerReference("test");
        blobContainer.CreateIfNotExists();
        string sourceBlob = @"xxxxx";
        CloudBlockBlob destPath = blobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference("sample.pdf");
        TransferManager.Configurations.ParallelOperations = 64;
        // Setup the transfer context and track the download progress
        SingleTransferContext context = new SingleTransferContext
        {
            ProgressHandler = new Progress<TransferStatus>(progress =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Bytes Upload: {0}", progress.BytesTransferred);
            })
        };
        // upload the blob
        Stopwatch stopWatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        var task = TransferManager.UploadAsync(
        sourceBlob, destPath, null, context, CancellationToken.None);
        task.Wait();
        stopWatch.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("Elapsed time: {0}", stopWatch.Elapsed);
    }
}
```

The above code executed and uploaded a large file to Azure blob storage.

**Portal:**

[image]